# VBA: Select index IE lists

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

Long time reader and first time poster.  I'm a little stuck with why I can't seem to select an index from a dropdown list from IE using this VBA code:

```
    IE.document.getElementById("ddlReportTemplate").Focus
    IE.document.getElementById("ddlReportTemplate").selectedIndex = 23
    IE.document.getElementById("ddlReportTemplate").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Here is the source code:

```
<select name="ddlReportTemplate" class="inputControl" id="ddlReportTemplate" style="width: 308px;" onchange="OnReportTemplateSelectionChanged(event)" autocomplete="off">
<option selected="selected" value="-1">Please select...</option>
<option value="21">Action Closeout Report</option>
<option value="19">Action Status Report</option>
<option value="8">Bi Monthly Report HAZID</option>
<option value="7">Bi Monthly Report HAZOP</option>
<option value="23">Combined Action Summary (Dashboard)</option>
<option value="20">Design Review Dump</option>
<option value="11">HAZOP Action Sheet Population</option>
<option value="22">HAZOP Data Dump</option>
<option value="18">NCOC Actions Closed this week (since 01/01/16)</option>
<option value="17">NCOC Actions Opened/Re-opened (since 01/01/16)</option>
<option value="13">NCOC Project Action Status</option>
<option value="6">Pisys Test</option>
<option value="27">PM660</option>
<option value="5">Project Action Overdue Report</option>
<option value="25">Shell GPS 'live' actions</option>
<option value="9">Test</option>
<option value="15">Weekly update</option>
<option value="10">WEL PSP Report dump</option>
<option value="24">Workpack Specific</option><option value="26">workpack 073</option>
```

I've also tried

```
With IE
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    IE.document.getElementByName("ddlReportTemplate")(0).Value = 23
    IE.document.getElementByName("ddlReportTemplate").FireEvent ("onchange")

End With
```

and I have defined IE as an object for IE and it opens the website already.

Not sure where the issue is, but I'm hoping someone on here will be a legend and find a solution to this.

Thanks :)

PS: Unfortunately I can't post the web address since it's company sensitive.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Also would help to show more code: how you load the page and how you wait for loading to complete etc

Answer (score 0):

The method is `getElementsByName`not `getElementByName`

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("ddlReportTemplate")(0).Value = 23
```

But since the `Select` has an `ID` I would use the `ID` instead,

```
IE.document.getElementById("ddlReportTemplate").Value = 23
```